# MySQL single query possible?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL statement:

```
SELECT name, ((AVG (q1) + AVG(q2) + AVG(q3) / 3) AS Average 
FROM tresults GROUP BY name ORDER BY name;
```

I also have another MySQL statment:

```
SELECT name, ((AVG (q1) + AVG(q2) + AVG(q3) / 3) AS Average 
FROM tresults WHERE q35 = 1 GROUP BY name ORDER BY name;
```

I've tried using subqueries but as it returns more than one row the following code doesn't work:

```
SELECT name, ((AVG (q1) + AVG(q2) + AVG(q3) / 3) AS Average,
  (SELECT ((AVG (q1) + AVG(q2) + AVG(q3) / 3) 
  FROM tresults WHERE q35 = 1 GROUP BY name ORDER BY name ) AS Average2  
FROM tresults GROUP BY name ORDER BY name;
```

Is it possible and what would the structure of the statement look like?

Thanks in advance for any and all feedback and advice.

Comment: Yoo could use UNION ALL between the 2 queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT name, 
       (AVG (AVG (q1) + AVG(q2) + AVG(q3) / 3) AS Average,
       (AVG (AVG (case when q35 = 1 then q1 else 0 end) + 
            (AVG (case when q35 = 1 then q2 else 0 end) + 
            (AVG (case when q35 = 1 then q3 else 0 end) / 3) AS q35_Average
FROM tresults 
GROUP BY name 
ORDER BY name
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're calculating the average of averages, it might be faster to use `sum` instead of using the `avg` function

```
select name,
    sum(q1+q2+q3)/sum(3) as average
    sum(case when q35 = 1 then (q1+q2+q3) else 0 end)
    / sum(case when q35 = 1 then 3 else 0 end) as q35_average
from tresults
group by name 
order by name
```